# When Access Token for Single User Application with Vimeo API 3.2 get expired?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using single user application with vimeo version 3.2 and generate access Token from my app page. Only concern i have when did this Access Token (which i generate with some scope) gets expired? (or Access Token never gets expired for single user application)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Vimeo access tokens never expire. This will change in the future, but we will retain backwards compatibility.